# How to fix 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined' in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I just get started with Javascript and Node.js. 
I have a server.js.

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/swag-shop');

var Product = require('./model/product');

app.post('/product', function(request, response) {
  var product = new Product();

  product.title = request.body.title;
  product.price = request.body.price;
  product.save(function(err, savedProduct) {
    if (err) {
      response.status(500).send({
        error: "Couldn't save product. Something is wrong!"
      });
    } else {
      response.send(savedProduct);
    }
  });
});
```

In this I refer to an other javascript. `(var Product = require('./model/product');)`

This is here:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var product = new Schema({
    title: String,
    price: Number,
    likes: {type: Number, default: 0},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', product);
```

I wanted to make a prototype with Postman, so I posted this json.

```
{
   "title":"ubi",
   "price":12.23
}
```

This is the error message what I got.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined at
>   C:\Personal\html-css\11-Intro_to_Node_Mongo_and_REST_APIs\swag-shop-api\server.js:11:51

Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: Did you `console.log` the request  ?

Comment: The error means that `request.body` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are wanting to access the body of the request, you can use the [bodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware to parse the request body

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Comment: It says that createServer is not a function. TypeError: express.createServer is not a function

Comment: @Piplikoc ,in your example, use express() instead of express.createServer() :)

Comment: I got this error, but I solved it. If someone has the same issue here is the solution.
Error: Most middleware (like bodyParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
I searched it, and I found the solution here. https://github.com/smurthas/fitbit-js/issues/15
You should type the `npm install express@">=3.0.0 <4.0.0" --save` command into the terminal.
Thank you for helping me, my problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(express.json())
```

Put this in your app.js