# How to solve "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I am using Postman to learn about APIs. The contents of my server.js file is in the code below. However, when I send a post through Postman, the error "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined" keeps showing.

```
var Product = require("./model/product");
var WishList = require("./model/wishlist");

app.post("/product", function (request, response) {
  var product = new Product();
  product.title = request.body.title;
  product.price = request.body.price;
  product.save(function (err, savedProduct) {
    if (err) {
      response.status(500).send({ error: "Could not save product" });
    } else {
      response.status(200).send(savedProduct);
    }
  });
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Swag Shop API runing on port 3000...");
});
```

The product.js file contains the code below.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var product = new Schema({
  title: String,
  price: Number,
  likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", product);
```

I tried to send the following json file through Postman but then the errorType: "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined " was showing.

```
{
    "title": "Test Title",
    "price": 100.00
}
```

These are the folders to see the location of my files: [Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAgn0.jpg).

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57094654/how-to-fix-typeerror-cannot-read-property-title-of-undefined-in-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top) using `npm install express@">=3.0.0 <4.0.0" --save` did not work in my case. After I used it in my terminal, the same error kept showing.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I would try to do a `console.log(request)` in `app.post()` success callback in order to see if it has the required properties.

Comment: do you use server and client-side debuggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and either use `express.json()` or `bodyParser.json()`

if you go into the file `node_module/express/lib/express.js` you can see under module dependencies body-parser module is already imported `var bodyParser = require('body-parser);`

```
var Product = require("./model/product");
var WishList = require("./model/wishlist");

//app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

 app.post("/product", function (request, response) {
 var product = new Product();
 product.title = request.body.title;
 product.price = request.body.price;
 product.save(function (err, savedProduct) {
  if (err) {
    response.status(500).send({ error: "Could not save product" });
  } else {
    response.status(200).send(savedProduct);
 }
 });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Swag Shop API runing on port 3000...");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install express.js & mongoose by typing $npm install --save
   express mongoose
2. Type the codes below on TOP for your proper
   imports and declarations

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/swag-shop');
```